# 502 Gate Way - nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu) Dropplet One-Click Django Server

Tags: django

My Droplet One-Click Django Server respponse 502 Bad GateWay Error.

Here is nginx error.log
2018/02/14 06:09:09 [error] 1486#1486: *3960 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 60.191.38.77, server: _, re$
2018/02/14 06:12:09 [error] 1493#1493: *1 connect() to unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 31.223.26.233, server: _, requ$

Here is gunicorn.conf

description "Gunicorn application server handling django_project"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid user
setgid www-data
chdir /home/user/django_project

exec myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

Comment: can you post your gunicorn configuration

Comment: where is gunicorn.conf i could not find it

Comment: Most propably `/etc/init/gunicorn.conf`

Comment: description "Gunicorn application server handling django_project"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid user
setgid www-data
chdir /home/user/django_project

exec myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock myproject.wsgi:application

Comment: In droplet 502 gateway error is mainly because of creating new directory or file with root account. Because in droplet you create a user named "django", to access local folder. Therefore if someone faces 502 gateway, i recommendt to check the files and directories permission and groups and owners ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to edit all these configuration files to work and you need to give permissions for read and write or execute to the files

`$ touch gunicorn_start`

`$ sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

`$ nano gunicorn_start`

Here we will put our configuration file which will be used at our service later

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="djproject"
DJANGODIR=/path/to
USER=root
GROUP=root or whatever the user used
WORKERS=3
BIND=unix:/path/to/gunicorn.sock
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mailqueue.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=mailqueue.wsgi
LOGLEVEL=error

cd $DJANGODIR
source /path/to/venv/bin/activate
cd djangoproject
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$PROJECTDIR:$PYTHONPATH

exec /path/to/venv/bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $WORKERS \
  --user=$USER \
  --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=$BIND \
  --log-level=$LOGLEVEL \
  --log-file=-
```

Make the file executable

`$ chmod u+x gunicorn_start`

Now we need to edit the service file to restart gracefully

```
$ sudo echo "

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root # or your user
Group=root # or your grp     
WorkingDirectory=/your-project-path/
ExecStart=/path/to/gunicorn_start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

" >  /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
```

#### Finally

Check the nginx configuration at `$ ls /etc/nginx/conf.d/`
if found any `*.conf` file edit it if not, `touch proj.conf`

```
$ sudo echo "
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/path/to/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 10.100.200.10;  # <- insert here the ip address/domain name

    keepalive_timeout 5;
    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /var/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /var/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /path/to/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /path/to/media/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files \$uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host \$http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
" >  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proj.conf;
```

#### Finally, make this [your reference](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-django-one-click-install-image-for-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: soryy but it Droplet-One Click Server and directories are different

Comment: Change the paths, it is easy, isn't it?